# Redirecting standard input/output/error streams with .NET's Process class

Tags: c#, process, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm trying to write a wrapper for an interactive console-based application. For this I use C# and the `Process` class. I'm trying to redirect `stdin`/`out`/`err`, but it doesn't work.

Example code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("admin.exe");
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

while (true)
{
    process.StandardInput.Write("uptime" + Environment.NewLine);
    process.StandardInput.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Nothing happens. But if I start `admin.exe` and write `uptime`, output is printed.

All solutions in the internet use `ReadToEnd`, but I can't use this because i have a dynamic communication on which I have to read `stdout`/`err` and write to `stdin`.

Has anyone an idea?

#### Update

I played with the posted zip on the linked thread. And then i tried to create a small 'proof-of-concept'-code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading; 

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Read(StreamReader reader)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int current;
                        while ((current = reader.Read()) >= 0)
                            Console.Write((char)current);
                    }
                }).Start();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe");
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            Read(process.StandardOutput);
            Read(process.StandardError);
            while (true)
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly:-)

But with the `admin.exe` it doesn't work? The `admin.exe` doesn't use any tricky input-method and it doesn't need an inputed password.

I know the `admin.exe` is written in c and compiled with mingw on linux. So i created a small dummy-tool:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int readed;
        while ((readed = fgetc(stdin)) >= 0)
                fputc((char)readed, stdout);
}
```

This tool does only echo the inputed text/line. I compiled it with `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc` and copied it to my windows machine. There i used the program on the top of this post to communicate with the `dummy.exe`. It doesn't work. No echo is shown. But why?

I compiled the dummy-code also with the Microsoft C++ Compiler, same effect.

#### Update2

(btw: Thanks to Tim Post)

I'm trying and trying. I tried to create a c-Tool, which does the same as my c# tool. I used `_popen`, but the effect was, that the output were shown at the end of the process. Hm, not good.

I found this alternative command shell for windows:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440269/whats-a-good-alternative-windows-console

http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

It seems to work. It gets the stdout/err in realtime, can redirect the stdin and `admin.exe` works. And it is opensource. May be i'll find the solution inside the C++-Code.

I'm not well in C++, so it's hard, but i'll try it. May be i have to write a "clear" redirect-wrapper in C/C++ and use it in C#.

If someone has an idea please say it, because the other way can be very hard (for me^^):-)

Thanks.

best regards

#### Update 3

Hm, i think this happens because the child-process (`admin.exe`) uses a few threads...
But how to solve it?

Comment: I had exactly this same problem, and came up with a (somewhat kludgy) solution that you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655613/net-why-does-process-standardoutput-read-block-when-i-set-startinfo-redirectsta/6656360#6656360 .  I believe that's got a link to a .ZIP with the full solution as well.

Comment: Some programs are just cranky about input/output redirection.  Admin.exe is a strong cue, it will want to read passwords from the true console.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts and converted your answer as an edit to your question, please check for accuracy. You should now have full control over your questions and answers.

Comment: You might be interested in [this post](http://www.codeducky.org/process-handling-net), which covers many of the intricacies of working with .NET processes, particularly around working with input and output. It recommends the [MedallionShell](https://github.com/madelson/MedallionShell) library, which simplifies dealing with process io streams

Comment: What if you readonce char at a time? ReadLine will require pressing enter. while (true)
   {
    p.StandardInput.Write(Console.ReadKey());
   }

Answer (score 1):

The problem *could be* because of you are using `Readline`, where the data are output from `admin.exe` application are sequentially and not in new lines.., try to use `Read` instead, and build the desirable string from it..

Also you don't have to use `Environment.NewLine` to write string followed by new line,  use `WriteLine` instead, so:

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("uptime");
```

Comment: There is no ReadLine() in the snippet.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to `BeginOutputReadLine` and so the `e.Data` in `OutputDataReceived` will just read lines, I think the same also apply to `BeginErrorReadLine` here..

Comment: You need to set UseShellExecute to true for the Verb to be respected and it must be set to 'false' to redirect standard output. You can't do both.

I'm pretty sure Windows also won't allow you to redirect standard input/output/error across the admin/non-admin security boundary. You'll have to find a different way to get output from the program running as admin - Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8690661