# C# Process StandardOutput. How to send Output from the ran EXE?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, output

I have two programs, one is a game and one is a launcher for the game. I created the launcher, in the first place, to receive basic information from the game and detect any kind of exit (crashes, Task Manager process stop, etc)

I will attach my current code for the process runner, it seems like all solutions on the internet, **but what I can't figure out is how to make the game send information to the launcher. I tried Console.WriteLine("login=..."); but it doesn't seem to send anything.**

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = "Game.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true}))
        {
            string output = "";
            while (!exeProcess.HasExited)
            {
                try
                {
                    output += exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n";
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    output += exc.Message + "::" + exc.InnerException + "\r\n";
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Have you developed the game or do you want it to work with any games?

Comment: See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/192b6df7-9437-42cf-81c1-c125021735ba and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655613/why-does-standardoutput-read-block-when-startinfo-redirectstandardinput-is-set for some ideas

Comment: @Romulus I am developing the game at the time being. It could be any program I'm creating, it's the first time I'm making a "launcher" as this time, it's important for me to know of any kind of exit. So basically, I'm going to use the launcher as a "container" for the game, to keep important data and use it after any kind of exit.

Comment: Console redirection only works on console mode programs, not the kind of target you'd select for a game.  It is a pretty miserable way to to process interop in general, many possible failure modes.  Do uplift this to one of the IPC mechanisms supported by .NET.  In a case like this, a Socket tends to fit the needs well.  Works across a network, you'll get a running start on a game server that supports multiplayer scenarios.

Comment: @Kfirprods: Can you have a look at my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your code, by adding the following line you can obtain error messages that were thrown by the game.

```
RedirectStandardError = true,
```

If you are developing your game in .NET you can return appropriate error codes as follows. Based on the error code you can then display appropriate messages in you launcher

```
    enum GameExitCodes
    {
        Normal=0,
        UnknownError=-1,
        OutOfMemory=-2
    }

    //Game Application
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Start game

            Environment.ExitCode = (int)GameExitCodes.Normal;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException)
        {
            Environment.ExitCode = (int)GameExitCodes.OutOfMemory;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Environment.ExitCode = (int)GameExitCodes.UnknownError;
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** You can take a look at this [**open source game launcher**](https://github.com/painejake/GameLauncher) developed in C# as a reference or modify it as per your needs.

**EDIT: Added info as per comment**

There are multiple ways to enable communication between between 2 .NET processes. They are

1. [Anonymous Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)
2. [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)
3. [Using Win32 WM_COPYDATA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19570/Inter-Process-Communication-with-C)
4. [MSMQ](http://fransiscuss.com/2012/06/01/msmq-basic-tutorial/)

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to transfer data, like a username or so. I do not think this is going to help me, but thanks a lot for trying to help anyways =)

Comment: Thanks! I used WM_COPYDATA and can now easily communicate between my programs

Comment: @Kfirprods: You are welcome. Was my pleasure. I knew about the pipes and MSMQ, but not about WM_COPYDATA. I learnt something new today too :).