# Why is Process.StandardError buffered

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, process, buffering

I have found numerous similar questions regarding Process.StandardOutput - one of the best here [How to disable output buffering in Process.StandardOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844267/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-process-standardoutput).

However those issues should not apply to standard error - as it should not be buffered.
Yet I still experience similar issues - I have an external app, that writes to stderr. When I redirect StandardError and then even read from the StandardError.BaseStream single byte at a time, then I still receive less input a time than what I can see when run in console.
The very interesting thing is that I even receive portion of the line written into stderr via fprintf by the called process and the second portion of the output is received many seconds after with other written lines.

Is there any hidden buffering option within .NET Process abstraction that can be used to influence this behavior?

Comment: The assumption that stderr is not buffered is not correct.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans - I tried to do more digging and was not able to find support for my claim (I probably mixed up with Linux, where stderr is allways unbuffered by default). However I haven't found any opposite info. If you have any pointers where to reasarch stderr bufferring bahavior on Windows and mainly how to influence it - I'd be grateful